# How to put condition in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two Class.College and Student, as below

```
Class College{
int id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID")
List<Student> std;

public void isElligible(){
// Some code here
}

}
```

I am persisting both these objects to corresponding tables. Now i want to persist data to STUDENT table only if isElligible returns true. How can i put that condition  ?
Can i use filter ?

Answer (score 0):

First, your mapping seems a bit off to me. Maybe it should look something like this:

```
class College {
  // ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="college")
  List<Student> students;
  // ...
}

class Student {
  // ...
  @ManyToOne(columnName="college_id", ...)
  College college;
  // ...
}
```

Second, about the conditional persitence of students, that should be treated in your persistence layer (or business logic layer, if you have it) not your model layer (the definition of your base entities).

Comment: I am new to hibernate. What do you mean by persistence layer here. Where exactly i can add the condition.

Comment: I'm saying that, typically, a project is divided in layers - in your case, it seems to me that you want to map your entity model to your database, and later you want to apply a certain business logic rule. This kind of rule is usually applied in a different project module, in order to have encapsulation, modularity and code independency between layers. So maybe, you should programmatically check if a Student is ellegible for your condition and persist it. You can more about this philosophy [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).